# Why CSS flex item get not stretched full width of it's parent

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following HTML structure for a full width clickable banner (with a close button):

```
<div class="banner">
 <button>Close</button>
 <a class="banner-link">
  <div class="banner-content">
   <span>Text</span>
   <span>More content</span>
   <span>More banner content</span>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

The css:

```
  .banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: ${theme.colors.black};
    z-index: 9001;
   }

  .banner-link {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
   }

   .banner-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
   }
```

Why is div `<div class="banner-content">` not stretched over the full 100% width? How to solve this issue?

Comment: Add `flex:1` to `banner-content`. You have to tell the element how much space to take up.

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried that but doesn't work?

Comment: Sure it does - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/PoeYzVV

Comment: @Paulie_D check Chrome dev tools in your example, `banner-content` isn't stretched

Comment: Stretched how? It's clearly 100% wide as the background proves. Dev tools are irrelevant here. Unless the width of the element is not the actual issue here.

Comment: @Paulie_D I expect e.g. the span `<span>More banner content</span>` to be totally at the right when its 100% width?

Comment: Well that's a different issue than the one asked in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex: 1;` to `.banner-content` then `justify-content: space-around;` will work as expected.

```css
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: $ {
    theme.colors.black
  }
  ;
  z-index: 9001;
}

.banner-link {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.banner-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <button>Close</button>
  <a class="banner-link">
    <div class="banner-content">
      <span>Text</span>
      <span>More content</span>
      <span>More banner content</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```